# app has stopped when adding adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I want to add ListView to my project(now I have there one TextView and one progressbar).
When i add adapter with listView my application stops(unfortunately app has stopped ) :/

my onCreate method in MainActivity class.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Pager settings
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    //Settings of progress bar
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);  
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Work in Progress ...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Anuluj", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            status = false;
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    //===========================================
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        
    int s=0;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        s++;
        if(s==3){
            s=0;
        }
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Item" + i);  
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[s]));            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }

    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};        
    SimpleAdapter adapter  = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview); 
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); <=== here is a problem ( i think).

}
```

It is a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/aaa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/in"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color" />




        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and listview_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"        

        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"            
        >    

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"             
        />          

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"        
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Can I add it in some different way ?

Cheers

EDIT:

It is a logcat

```
    07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo/in.sirocco.exercise.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at in.sirocco.exercise.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-07 14:17:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please give us the full stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: sorry, i forgot about it -

Comment: Where is line 86 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

As per your code (snippet below), it seems that activity_main has a pager component in it.  However, the layout file that you have shared does not have it.  Now, since you are looking for R.id.listview in same layout file as that contained R.id.pager, obviously, there is something wrong.

So, I am assuming that your expectation that there is a component R.id.listview present in layout is wrong, and hence you are getting null pointer exception

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Pager settings
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

....
ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);  //this is null
```

Comment: thanks, but I still do not know how i can repair it. Can you suggest me something ?

Comment: I think the list view has to be accessed inside MyFragmentPagerAdapter  assuming that it is part of a fragment that is being displayed in pager